# gdb hook to set break

Tags: gdb

When debugging an unfamiliar program with gdb, the program often unexpectedly exits after executing `next`.  When that happens I'll typically set a break point, re-run the program and execute `step` instead of `next` to trace what's happening.  However, sometimes it is difficult to know where to set the break point.  Is there a technique set the break automatically?  Something like:

```
define hook-next
break
end

define hookpost-next
# delete the previous break if the program is still running
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could do it with a combination of hook-next, convenience variables, and a breakpoint on exit.  Something like:

```
define hook-next
set $saved_pc = $pc
end

break exit
commands
break *$saved_pc
end
```

You may prefer "tbreak" there.